# Customising Mobius Forms

Tags: 2sxc

I'm really keen to use the 2sxc environment on my website for a number of applications.

I'm currently looking at the Mobius forms.

What I'm wanting to do is create a ticket in ConnectWise rather than send an email, using the ConnectWise REST API.

Some of these questions might have obvious answers to someone who has been taught in these technologies, but I'm self-taught. When I went to school I learnt COBOL!

There is c# code in the application, but I can't see how you build and incorporate into the application. I forked the code and it seems to just code with no build.

There are live and staging folders with the same cshtml files. However, it seems a bit random when the live or staging is actually used. For example, I did a quick fix to the _Contact Form.cshtml so to fix the type that meant it always displayed the ReCaptcha warning, and I changed the live version, which didn't do anything, so I had to change the staging version.

I need to update the settings so that configure the ConnectWise API settings, I haven't been able to find where I can do this? I am still looking though.

I also need to store a private key in the settings. Is there a secure way I can do this?

PS. When I get my head around all this I'm happy to be a contributor

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow.

I'll try to give you some guidance to help you figure it out

1. Live and staging are folders meant to let you make changes while the users see the unmodified output. So a host-user sees the files from staging, others see what's in live. When you're done and all is tested, you copy from staging to live. This we call [Polymorphism](https://r.2sxc.org/polymorphism).
2. Polymorphism applies to both the `cshtml` as well as the `api`. So as a host-user, you'll be using `staging/api/FormController` to save/send.
3. There is no build process, everything is hot-compiled. That's one of the things that makes 2sxc so amazing. No Visual Studio, DLL or restarting the application ;) You'll love it.
4. Secure keys: there is no special secure key storage. We usually put it in the App-Settings, just like the MailChimp key you'll see there. We split it into two fields for very technical reasons, because we publish our code on github and that causes trouble when our code has API keys. But you can just use one field, assuming you don't plan on publishing the code on github.